# Limiting ngfor based on conditions

Tags: angular, typescript

I am limiting the number of iterations as like below in angular:

```html
<div class="form-check py-1" *ngFor="let brand of manufacturer | slice:0:5 let i=index;">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [value]="brand">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">{{brand}}</label>
</div>
<a href="#." class="mb-3 d-block">View More > </a>
```

but, by default only 5 records shown, if we clicked on "view more", all records will need shown.

Comment: I would suggest adding what you've tried to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using constant 5 in the slice pipe, you could declare a variable in the controller that can be changed in the `View More`'s `click` event handler.

Try the following

Controller

```
@Component({...})
export class SampleComponent {
  end = 5;      // <-- default value
  ...
}
```

Template

```html
<div class="form-check py-1" *ngFor="let brand of manufacturer | slice:0:end; let i=index;"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [value]="brand">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">{{brand}}</label>
</div>
<a href="#." class="mb-3 d-block" (click)="end=manufacturer.length">View More > </a>
```